# Remove character from image name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove part of the name of the image to create thumbnails.

The image name is created dynamically ie HG57JWY_0.jpg, HG57JWY_1.jpg, HG57JWY_2.jpg. I managed to remove the .jpg using:

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w*)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1];
```

My problem is that i cant figure how to remove the "_0"

```
return '<img src="sample-img/'+ imageName +'_' + [i -+ 1] + '.jpg">';
```

this generates HG57JWY_0_0.jpg

Any ideas how i do that?

Edit:
Forgot to mention that big image and the thumb are in different folder.
So i display the big image in one place holder with the src = http://mydomain.com/sample-img/imagename.jpg

and i place the thumbs in a list with the src = http://mydomain.com/sample-img-thumb/imagename.jpg

Edit 2:

Thanks to Alexander, i used my original code

```
 var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w*)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1];
```

and added his .split("_")[0]

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w*)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1].split("_")[0];
```

This takes the whole image src ie `http://mydomain/imageFolder/image_1.jpg`, and returns just the "image".

Then i was able to use what ever path i want with

```
return '<img src="sample-img/'+ imageName +'_' + [i -+ 1] + '.jpg">';
```

and just changed the sample-img/ with what i needed.

Comment: Basically, the format of the string of the image name was not what you originally believed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').split("_")[0];
```

**UPDATE**

You could use `split` in your match:

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src')
                                    .match(/(\w*)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1]
                                    .split("_")[0];
```

Or, modifying your regular expression (as shown also in [Dave Rager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416627)'s answer) to exclude the matching of the pattern `_number`:

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w+)_\d+\.\w{3,4}$/)[1]
```

Comment: This works but not quite, i guess because i forgot to mention that the large image and the thumb are in different folders. Edited.

Comment: @cac, Sorry, but how is that suppose to be relevant?

Comment: When i use your code, it returns the whole image path. I need only the image name with out the _0 etc.

Comment: Figured it out mate, i used your .split("_")[0] at the end of mine original code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cac, well, that's certainly a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If the image name guaranteed to contain "_x" then try:

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w*)_\d+\.\w{3,4}$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#slider1 li img').prop('src', function(i, value) {
    return value.substr(0, value.indexOf('_'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageName = $('#slider1 li img').prop('src').match(/(\w*)(_[0-9]+)\.\w{3,4}$/)[1];
```